# Incremental uploading of file using signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, azure-storage, signals-slots, qnetworkaccessmanager

Before implementing this I would like to check if this will lead to undefined behaviour or race conditions.

When uploading files to asure, this must be done in blocks. I want to upload 5 blocks in parallel and they all get their data from the same file. This would happen like this:

```
char *currentDataChunk;
int currentDataChunkSize;

connect(_blobStorageProvider, SIGNAL(putBlockSucceded(int)), this, SLOT(finalizeAndUploadNextBlock(int)));

int parallelUploads = ((_item->size() / MAX_BLOCK_SIZE) >= MAX_PARALLEL_BLOCKUPLOADS) ? MAX_PARALLEL_BLOCKUPLOADS : (_item->size() / MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);

_latestProcessedBlockId = (parallelUploads - 1);

for(int i = 0; i < parallelUploads; i++) {

    currentDataChunkSize = _item->read(currentDataChunk, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);

    ...

    uploader->putBlock(_container, _blobName, currentDataChunk, i);
}
```

In the putBlock function in the uploader, it calls the QNetworkAccessManager with the call. When it's done it sends back a signal if it failed, succeded or got canceled, along with the blockId so that I know which one of the blocks that was uploaded.

```
void BigBlobUploader::finalizeAndUploadNextBlock(int blockId) {

    // FINALIZE BY ADDING SUCCESSFUL BLOCK TO FUTURE BLOCKLIST
    QByteArray temp;

    for(int i = 0; i != sizeof(blockId); i++) {
        temp.append((char)(blockId >> (i * 8)));
    }

    _uploadedBlockIds.insert(blockId, QString(temp.toBase64()));
    this->uploadNextBlock();
} 

void BigBlobUploader::uploadNextBlock() {

    char *newDataChunk;
    int newDataChunkSize = _item->read(newDataChunk, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);
    ...
    _latestProcessedBlockId++;
    uploader->putBlock(_container, _blobName, newDataChunk, _latestProcessedBlockId);
}
```

My plan now is to fetch these signals to a slot which should take note that this block was uploaded (put it in a list to be able to put a block list to finalize this blob), increase the index by one (which starts at 5) and fetch a new chunk of data and redo the whole process.

My issue now is, what if two of them finishes at the EXACT same time? I'm not dealing with threads here but since the HTTP requests are threaded by default, what is the case here? Are the signals queued (or should I use QueuedConnection)? Can a slot be called in parallel? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience, I assumed you were using .NET since you added the Windows Azure tag to this thread. I'm familar with Windows Azure, but my understanding about Qt is limited. However, it would not be different from using signals/slots in other concurrent scenarios. This document may help: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with QNetworkAccessManager. But in general, to deal with race conditions, please use locks. Usually, the way to use locks in C# is leveraging the lock keyword. Something like:

```
private object lockingObject = new object();

In a method:

lock
{
                // If a thread acquires a lock, another thread is blocked here until the lock is released.
}
```

In addition, you can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.100).aspx for more information.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: the things is, I wont have different threads accessing this slot and I need to know how this will work with the signal/slot mechanism in qt/c++, not c#